# How to export all users of wikipedia to your localhost?

Tags: sql, import, export, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I want to export

1. All users participating in deletion debate of Wikipedia.
2. All users participating in editing of an article.
3. The articles have been proposed for deletion.
4. The deletion debate itself.

I setup an empty local copy of Wikipedia in my local computer. I have found out the following export way from wikipedia:

1. Using xml special export of wikipedia.
2. Using wikipedia API Table.
3. Dump file from wikipedia download.

Besides, i have used the following tools to import them:

1. Using import xml dump.
2. Using MWDumper which is in java.
3. Using Data dumps/xml2sql.

However, still could not get what i want. For example, I go to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export%20and%20search%20for:%20%E2%80%9C%E2%80%9CAfD%20debates%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%9CAll%20articles%20proposed%20for%20deletion%E2%80%9D) and search for:

- “AfD debates”
- “All articles proposed for deletion”

So, in this example, i have successfully export the debate here successfully, as i could see them in the xml file, however, i could not import the debate to the local server successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The `user` table of Wikimedia projects is not available for download. See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T51132

It's not needed for the use you describe, only if you want to set up a fork. For that, there is [MediaWikiAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MediaWikiAuth) which creates "shadow" accounts and fills them upon login by themselves.